# How to display multiple records fetched in JSON from server using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Trying to post to a PHP file that returns a JSON response and then use
it to display results but only one record is displayed with undefined
values.

Here is the JSON response from `core/backend/comm.php`:

```
{
    "name": "Rehan",
    "location": "Pune",
    "description": "hello hi",
    "created_by": 13692,
    "username": "xyz",
},
{
    "name": "Sameer",
    "location": "Bangalore",
    "description": "how are you",
    "created_by": 13543,
    "username": "abc",
},
<!--JSON RESPONSE ENDS-->
```

Here is the code that I have tried but not working:

```
$('[id^="cat"]').click(function() {
   // do something
  var prot= this.getAttribute("prot");


       jQuery.ajax({
    url: "core/backend/comm.php",
    data:{ prot: prot }, 
    // $("#query_form").serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){

    // $("#repo").html(data);

data = [data];
var htmlText = '';

            for ( var key in data ) {
                htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
                htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].name + '</p>';
                htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> Location: ' + data[key].location + '</p>';
                htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
                htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Created by: ' + data[key].created_by + '</p>';
                htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].username + '</p>';
                htmlText += '</div>';
            }

            $('#repo').append(htmlText);


    },

    error:function (){}
    });

});
```

> Corrected Code:

```
$('[id^="cat_"]').click(function() {
   // do something
  var prot= this.getAttribute("prot");


    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "core/backend/comm.php",
    // dataType: "text",
    data:{ prot: prot }, 
    // $("#query_form").serialize(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){

    // $("#repo").html(data);
console.log(data);
var data = JSON.parse(data);
var htmlText = '';

            for ( var key in data ) {
                    htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
                    htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[key].name + '</p>';
                    htmlText += '<p class="p-loc"> Location: ' + data[key].location + '</p>';
                    htmlText += '<p class="p-desc"> Description: ' + data[key].description + '</p>';
                    htmlText += '<p class="p-created"> Created by: ' + data[key].created_by + '</p>';
                    htmlText += '<p class="p-uname"> Username: ' + data[key].username + '</p>';
                    htmlText += '</div>';
                }

                $('#repo').append(htmlText);


    },

    error:function (){}
    });




});
```

> Here is the corrected JSON response:

```
[ {
        "name": "Rehan",
        "location": "Pune",
        "description": "hello hi",
        "created_by": 13692,
        "username": "xyz"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sameer",
        "location": "Bangalore",
        "description": "how are you",
        "created_by": 13543,
        "username": "abc"
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this unpredictable behavior is that you are using wrong dataType in your ajax call. You are using dataType: 'text' when what you need is clearly dataType: 'json' or you could even ommit dataType as by default jquery uses Intelligent Guess for data types xml, json, script, or html.
Documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

jQuery tries to guess dataType based on the MIME type of the response. That means that if one ommits the dataType in an ajax call, the correct 'Content-type' header (application/json) should be used in the response by the PHP code. If you are not sure that this is the case, use dataType: 'json'.

Finally, one can always use JSON.parse(data); to deserialize a JSON array if it is returned in string format.

Comment: Tried removing dataType: "text", but its still not working

Comment: Did you try to output the returned data in your console? Use console.log(data); in your success function to see what you are really getting as a response.

Comment: console response for data is sending the exact information that is being sent by comm.php which is:
{
    "name": "Rehan",
    "location": "Pune",
    "description": "hello hi",
    "created_by": 13692,
    "username": "xyz",
},
{
    "name": "Sameer",
    "location": "Bangalore",
    "description": "how are you",
    "created_by": 13543,
    "username": "abc",
},
The undefined response is generated once which should be twice. The code is terminated the moment it returns a single result. Also the values are still undefined.

Comment: which is not a valid JSON. 
1. You should have opening and closing brackets because you want to get an array of json objects.
2. You have a comma after "username": "xyz" in the first JSON object but you shouldn't
3. You have a comma after "username": "abc" in the second JSON object but you shouldn't
4. You have a comma after the last } where you should have only the closing bracket

Comment: This is my response now:

[
                           
{
    "name": "Rehan",
    "location": "Pune",
    "description": "hello hi",
    "created_by": 13692,
    "username": "xyz"
},
{
    "name": "Sameer",
    "location": "Bangalore",
    "description": "how are you",
    "created_by": 13543,
    "username": "abc"
}]

But the response is still the same. One result with undefined values.

Comment: Use var dataArray = JSON.parse(data); to deserialize the returned data.